# Is there a way to lock the access to a folder for x days?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, steam

I need a method to lock the access to a folder from myself any allowed it to open only at weekends.

I'm addicted to gaming and right now I have to delete my games (steam) and download it again every weekend.

Comment: If you can lock it you can unlock it. You need to get someone else to lock if for you.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm looking for a method like the chrome extensions StayFocusd